# catch block is not called with async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was just trying to fetch some data when my internet connection was turned off. So node fetch rejected the promise I returned. But the problem is that my code was not halted and catch block was not called. It just continued executing to the next line.

My code with try catch block :

```
router.get("/test" , async (req , res , next) => {
    try {
        let params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.set('student_id' , 'some_id');
        params.set('password' , 'some_password');
        let studentInfo = await fetchStudentInfo(params);

        return res.json(studentInfo);

    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
```

The function for fetching data :

```js
function fetchFacultyInfo(params) {

    let url = "https://somesiteasdasdadsa.com?";

    return fetch(url + params)
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then(jsonData => {
            return jsonData;
        })
        .catch(e => {
            return e;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a rejected Promise and call `.catch` on it, unless something inside the `catch` throws, it will return a *resolved* Promise. Since you're `.catch`ing here, the `fetchFacultyInfo` function will return a Promise that always resolves.

It's also a good idea to usually only catch errors when you're actually able to handle them in some way at that point - otherwise, just let the error percolate up the call stack until an error handler which *can* handle it sees it:

```
function fetchFacultyInfo(params) {
    let url = "https://somesiteasdasdadsa.com?";
    return fetch(url + params)
        .then(result => result.json())
}
```

This way, if the `fetch` or `json()` rejects, the `await fetchStudentInfo(params);` will fail, and send control flow into the `catch` block which calls `next`.

Comment: Thank you I get it now. I though returning the error will also return a rejected promise.

Comment: @AlifHasnain You can do it as in your code just replace `return` with `throw` in your `.catch()`. Using `return` converts the error to a normal return, using `throw` will return an error. You can call `throw` in either `.catch()` or `.then()` and you can call `return` in either `.catch()` or `.then()`